# Which famous Rabbi had lifelong stomach pain?

Tags: history, rabbis, historical-figures, acharonim, handicap-disabled-impair

I recently heard a shiur that quoted a famous rabbi (I think an Acharon) who talked about having stomach pain every day of his life, and studying torah was the only thing that gave him any joy. Does anyone know who this was?

For some reason I thought I remembered it being the Chasam Sofer, but I can't find anything about it.

Comment: Welcome human, we could use more humans round here! Not an Acharon, but Rebbi had bowel disease his whole life: https://www.jstor.org/stable/27913592

Comment: @RabbiKaii [Bava M'tzi'a 85a](https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Metzia.85a.3?lang=bi), ['Avoda Zara 40b](https://www.sefaria.org/Avodah_Zarah.40b.8?lang=bi).

Comment: Thanks @Fred I was too loose with the term "whole life", and that clarifies it

Comment: Related:https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/125939/is-there-a-prayer-for-an-easy-death/125943#125943