# Traditional wording for asking for a kind, even quick, death?

Tags: prayer-book

This question asks about the wording for prayer(s) for the terminally ill.

This posting ([Davening for the interminably ill](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/48492/davening-for-the-interminably-ill)) suggests that it is inappropriate to praying for the recovery of a person who is terminally ill.  Thus, it is inappropriate to use the typical wording: healing of soul and body for such a person.

This posting says it is appropriate to pray for an easy death [Is there a prayer "for an easy death"?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/125939/is-there-a-prayer-for-an-easy-death)

The current posting asks if there is traditional wording for asking for a kind, even quick, death.

Comment: As I was saying when DoubleAA so rudely shut me up, how do you know someone is "terminally ill"?

Comment: @MauriceMizrahi  Medical doctors have some success predicting the terminal disease phase of serious illnesses.  The accuracy of prediction varies by disease and stage (e.g. it is easier in cases of metastasized lung cancer,especially in elderly, otherwise compromised people).

Comment: You can pray for *anybody* to have a quick and painless death when his time comes, even one who is young and healthy.  It won't hurt.  (But don't let him know if you value your teeth.)  But to do so *only* for someone is "expected" to die soon seems to me to be callous and unfeeling.  Would it be too much to ask to pray, instead, "for his recovery, and, if the decree has already been issued, for a quick and painless death"?